# How to merge same values together using C# and ClosedXML?

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I'm trying to merge the same values together for Excel using ClosedXML package in C#.

This is my current output.. it's not merging the same values together and leaving some out.

> e.g. No.7 merged two cells and not the third.

> e.g. No.9 keeps merging 2 cells and repeats the same merge.

[image]

My current logic:

```
// Foreach record
int i = 1;

foreach (var record in ...)
{
    i++;

    // Minimum Months
    // Create Value
    worksheet.Cell($"D{i}").Value = record.MinimumMonths.ToString();


    // Evaluate value - if they're the same then merge
    if(i > 2 && worksheet.Cell($"D{i}").Value.ToString() == worksheet.Cell($"D{i - 1}").Value.ToString())
    {
        worksheet.Range($"D{i - 1}:D{i}").Merge();
    }    
}
```

I don't understand where my logic is going wrong. How can I merge all the same values together?

Answer (score 1):

> `worksheet.Range($"D{i - 1}:D{i}").Merge();`

You shouldn't be merging your cells in pairs. Identify the first and last cells of a range of cells with the same value and merge that entire range in one `.Merge()` statement.

Also notice that when you merge a range of cells, only the top left cell keeps its value. All the other cells' values in the merged range are cleared. This is in line with what Excel does.

Your `.Value.ToString()` equality comparison is a bit naive. Rather check with `cell1.Value is double d1 && cell2.Value is double d2 && d1.Equals(d2)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't quite understand your last comment regarding checking the cell value. What is `cell1` and what do you mean by `double`?